# jQuery Search Filter in Rails 4 Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a listings table and in that table there is a square_feet column. I am trying to build a filter so I can enter the low end and the high end of a square footage range and then have those results display on the page and hide the rest. This JS is being used with Rails 4. Currently, when I enter a value regardless of which field, nothing happens.

HTML/ERB:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="general-text-field listing-filter" placeholder="Min Sq Ft" id="min-square-footage">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="general-text-field listing-filter" placeholder="Max Sq Ft" id="max-square-footage">
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
// square footage
var minSquareFootage = $.trim($("#min-square-footage").val()),
    maxSquareFootage = $.trim($("#max-square-footage").val());

minSquareFootage = (minSquareFootage.length > 0) ? parseFloat(minSquareFootage) : null;
maxSquareFootage = (maxSquareFootage.length > 0) ? parseFloat(maxSquareFootage) : null;

rows.each(function(idx, elem) {
   var rowSquareFeet = $(this).data("square_feet"),
     inRange = true;

   if (minSquareFootage) {
     inRange = inRange && (rowSquareFeet >= minSquareFootage);
   }

   if (maxSquareFootage) {
     inRange = inRange && (rowSquareFeet <= maxSquareFootage);
   }

   console.log('rowSquareFeet: ' + rowSquareFeet, 'inRange: ' + inRange);
   console.log(elem)

   $(elem).toggle(inRange);
});
```

Comment: jQuery and TurboLinks don't always place nice together.  Checkout: https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails

Comment: Please post yout HTML for table and code of how are you creating `rows`.

Comment: @jake-kaad I have that installed already.